# PHP SoapClient Timeout

Tags: php, web-services, timeout, soap-client

Is there anyway for a SoapClient Request to time out and throw an exception. As of now, I get PHP Server response timeout, in my case 60 seconds. Basically what I want is, if there isn't any reply from the Web Service within certain time, an exception would be thrown and I could catch it. The 60 seconds warning is not what I want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Timing Out PHP Soap Calls by Robert; 21 Oct 2009](http://www.darqbyte.com/2009/10/21/timing-out-php-soap-calls/)

if you are comfortable and your environment allows you to extend classes.

It basically extends the `SoapClient` class, replaces the HTTP transport with curl which can handle the timeouts:

```
class SoapClientTimeout extends SoapClient
{
    private $timeout;

    public function __setTimeout($timeout)
    {
        if (!is_int($timeout) && !is_null($timeout))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid timeout value");
        }

        $this->timeout = $timeout;
    }

    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = FALSE)
    {
        if (!$this->timeout)
        {
            // Call via parent because we require no timeout
            $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        }
        else
        {
            // Call via Curl and use the timeout
            $curl = curl_init($location);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);

            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            if (curl_errno($curl))
            {
                throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
            }

            curl_close($curl);
        }

        // Return?
        if (!$one_way)
        {
            return ($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That would be one place to have  a look.
Lets see if there is any other.

Comment: I've tried this in PHP 5.4.6, but it seems, they have changed the signature of `_doRequest()` without further notice. `$request` does not contain the raw XML anymore, but rather a string like `141201299690460051141201717499383133141201717499423132141201717499443131141201717499463131141201717499483135false`. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: This would break the whole internals of the SoapClient.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl can you provide some more info? This could be a big problem, but i'm having a difficult time reproducing this.

Comment: @Nanne Unfortunately not. I'm not sure what caused the issues I had and what I changed to fix it. But from looking at my code, I've ended up using a similar approach to the solution described here and it worked. But maybe I've simply upgraded to a later PHP version than 5.4.6. Don't remember.

Comment: Sorry, broken link

Comment: Din't work entirely. I had to also add header `'SOAPAction: ' . $action.`

Answer (score 68):

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 15);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(......));
```

> The connection_timeout option defines a timeout in seconds for the
>   connection to the SOAP service. This option does not define a timeout
>   for services with slow responses. To limit the time to wait for calls
>   to finish the default_socket_timeout setting is available.

Comment: This is the answer. :)

Comment: This is a nice answer as long as the socket timeout is not exceeded. Otherwise the server will throw a Connection Timeout and execution will stop...

Comment: Also note, that there's still this unsolved PHP-Bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41631. So `default_socket_timeout` may not work with HTTPS connections

Comment: `default_socket_timeout` works for service with slow response. The question was about handling a service that's _not_ responding.

Comment: @T30 - it's the same thing.  In either case this setting will kill the request after X seconds.

Answer (score 61):

#### Invalid answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12119215/441739 instead.

---

> While Andrei linked to a decent solution, this one has less code yet arrives at a good solution:
>
>  * [Handling Timeouts with PHP5 SoapClient Extension (by Antonio Ramirez; 02 Feb 2010)](http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2010/02/02/handling-timeouts-with-php5-soapclient-extension/)
>
>  Example code:
>     //
>     // setting a connection timeout (fifteen seconds on the example)
>     //
>     $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("connection_timeout" => 15));
>
> And there is also the stream context, if you need more fine-grained HTTP control. See the `stream_context` option for [`new SoapClient()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php). Under the surface `SoapClient` uses the HTTP and SSL transports.

Comment: When I use this, I get `Unknown SOAP client option` Exception

Comment: @DanFromGermany, what version of PHP are you running? Are you passing any options other than what's shown above?

Comment: PHP 5.3, I'm also passing `'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,` but I'm using `Zend_Soap_Client`, but it just extends `SoapClient`

Comment: @DanFromGermany, actually Zend_Soap_Client wraps SoapClient, rather than extend it. You can see the list of options that Zend_Soap_Client supports here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php#L166   << You'll notice that `connection_timeout` isn't a supported option.

Comment: Sorry, broken link.

Comment: Per php docs this timeout only affects the connection to the service, not the time the operation actually takes. You need to set the `default_socket_timeout` like mentioned below

Comment: @billynoah, thanks, I've edited to point to correct answer

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer will break all functionalities that SoapClient has to offer. Like setting the correct content headers, authentication etc.

This would be a better solution to the problem

```
class MySoapClient extends \SoapClient
{
    private $timeout = 10;

    public function __construct($wsdl, array $options)
    {
        // Defines a timeout in seconds for the connection to the SOAP service.
        // This option does not define a timeout for services with slow responses.
        // To limit the time to wait for calls to finish the default_socket_timeout setting is available.
        if (!isset($options['connection_timeout'])) {
            $options['connection_timeout'] = $this->timeout;
        }

        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    public function setTimeout($timeout)
    {
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
    }

    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        $original = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $this->timeout);
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $original);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Comment: For an extra safety net you should try/catch the parent call (e.g. Some apps/frameworks could throw Exceptions on Warnings via a custom error_handler) which would otherwise leave the un-resetted `default_socket_timeout`

Comment: The connection_timeout itself should default to a value a lot smaller then 10secs.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use [stream_context_create()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and add the `timeout` option to the `http` array:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            "timeout" => 10,
        ),
    )
);
```

[Here is the PHP manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.timeout)

The SoapHandler initialization then should be:

```
$soapHandler = new SoapClient($wsdl, [
    //more params, if needed..
    
    'stream_context' => $context,
]);
```

Comment: working for me. thanks

Comment: It works, but how to detect that a timeout has occurred?

Comment: I would compare the elapsed time to the timeout in case of an exception. If they're close, you got a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You can install this through composer:
https://github.com/ideaconnect/idct-soap-client

It extends the standard SoapClient and gives options to set the amount of retries, connection and read timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following logic when working with SOAPClient:

```
public function executeSoapCall($method, $params)
{
    try {
        $client = $this->tryGetSoapClient();

        $timeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 60);//set new timeout value - 60 seconds
        $client->__soapCall($method, $params);//execute SOAP call
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $timeout);//revert timeout back
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        if (isset($timeout)) {
            ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $timeout);//revert timeout back
        }
    }
}
protected function tryGetSoapClient()
{
    $timeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');//get timeout (need to be reverted back afterwards)
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);//set new timeout value - 10 seconds
    try {
        $client = new \SoapClient($this->wsdl, $this->options);//get SOAP client
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);//revert back in case of exception
        throw $e;
    }
    $this->iniSetTimeout($timeout);//revert back

    return $client;
}
```

This helps me to wait up to 10 seconds for connection establishment, and 60 seconds for the call execution.