# SoapClient / Zend_Soap_Client with timeout

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, stream, timeout

I'm using the following method trying to set a timeout to the SoapClient. `$this->_soap` is a `Zend_Soap_Client` which wraps a  `SoapClient` object.

Sometimes the API call I'm doing takes > 60 seconds. I'm trying to set a 10 seconds timeout but this doesn't work.

**1.** Using `stream_context_create`:

```
public function setTimeout($timeout)
{
    $this->_soap->setStreamContext(stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => intval($timeout)
        )
    )));
}
```

**2.** I tried as Part of the constructor, like in this answer ([PHP SoapClient Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500527/php-soapclient-timeout/10485102#10485102)) which is working with `SoapClient` object:

```
    $this->_soap     = new \Zend_Soap_Client($this->_wsdl, array(
        'soap_version'       => SOAP_1_1,
        'connection_timeout' => intval($timeout)
    ));
```

But it is not working because Zend doesn't support this option and throws `Unknown SOAP client option`.

**3.** I tried `default_socket_timeout`:

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", intval($timeout));
```

None of those did work:

```
 API calls times (seconds):     min 0.3012      max 23.0334     avg 2.5005
```

What I **could try** now is, to append to the `public function setOptions($options)` in "\Zend\Soap\Client.php" with a timeout, but I don't want to touch the Zend core files..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that dynamically setting the `timeout` option is possible.

However, can you try this method?

```
$this->_soap->setSoapClient(
    new SoapClient(
        $this->_wsdl, 
        array(
            'soap_version'       => SOAP_1_1,
            'connection_timeout' => intval($timeout)
        )
    )
);
```

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: Due to our project specifications, I must to use the `Zend_Soap_Client`. Maybe I can convince them to this solution, otherwise they have to live with a very slow cronjob.

Comment: @DanFromGermany : `_soap` is still a `Zend_Soap_Client`! The `setSoapClient` method is a `Zend_Soap_Client` method. As you can see in the `Zend_Soap_Client` class definition, it's internally using the PHP `SoapClient` class.

Comment: You are right, I just saw this after looking at the source of `\Zend\Soap\Client.php`.

Answer (score 2):

In documentation: [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php):

> The *connection_timeout* option defines a timeout in seconds for the connection to the SOAP service. This option does not define a timeout for services with slow responses. To limit the time to wait for calls to finish the [default_socket_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) setting is available.

Answer (score 2):

About your trial 2, there is the issue [ZF-9125: connection_timeout option not supported in Zend_Soap_Client](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9125).
There is an extend Zend_Soap_Client as solution.

Maybe it will help you. :)

Comment: Interesting! Thx for the link