# How to override SoapClient::__doRequest()?

Tags: php, soap

I want to override `SoapClient::__doRequest()` in my custom class and use my own curl based transport, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500527/php-soapclient-timeout).

According to the PHP manual, `__doRequest()` has this signature:

`public string SoapClient::__doRequest ( string $request , string $location , string $action , int $version [, int $one_way = 0 ] )`

And the `$request` parameter is:

- `request` The XML SOAP request.

But this seems to be wrong. I don't get any XML in `$request` but a cryptic string like:

```
string(1496) " 14120188025349F
```

Here's the simple class I've used:

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = false)
    {
        var_dump($request);
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }
}
```

So what is wrong? Did they somehow change the internal implementation of this without updating the manual? For reference, my PHP version is 5.4.6 on a Ubuntu 12.10 box.

Comment: I haven't that much experience with soap, but maybe it's compressed. The string is long enough to be a compressed request.

Comment: @Johni How would I find out and how would I uncompress that string?