# Error handling for PHP SoapClient when API server is down

Tags: php, web-services, error-handling, soap-client

I'm using an API for sending SMS in my PHP web aplication. I am using the [PHP SoapCLient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) to send requests to the API, but how do I handle the case that the API server is down?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500527/php-soapclient-timeout. There they created a wrapper for the Soap client which can handle a timeout.

Comment: Thanks @CodyKL, but as you can see in accepted answer's comments it is not working properly, I thinks set time out in ini_set() is better